# Debugging OSGi modules in Liferay with IntelliJ?

Tags: debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea, liferay, osgi

I'm trying to debug an OSGi module I created with IntelliJ. I've followed the steps mentioned in [this blog post](https://web.liferay.com/es/web/user.26526/blog/-/blogs/debugging-liferay-7-in-intellij). However I'm using the [Liferay Workspace](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/liferay-workspace) provided by Blade CLI to do all development and also note that Tomcat is embedded in my `bundles` directory within the workspace.

After I copied the contents of `startup.sh` and pasted them in a new file called `debug.sh` I added `jpda` before the start command. I relaunched the Liferay instance using the `debug.sh` script. Then I configured a new debug configuration in IntelliJ as the pictures of the blog post show. Although one of the things I had to change is the port, my Tomcat is running in port 8080, whereas in the tutorial it says 8000. Here is my debug configuration:
[image: Liferay IntelliJ debug configuration]

Then I set a breakpoint, deploy succesfully my module and attempt to run from IntelliJ on debug but then the following error happens:

`Error running LR 7 Remote Debug: Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8080): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"`

Any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Port 8080 is also the default for HTTP ... You might have a port conflict

Comment: How will I go about changing the port in which Liferay should be launched?

Comment: Just use e.g. 4044 for the debug port. You could also make suspend=y so that Liferay does not start before your debugger is attached

Comment: I've tried changing the port of the debugger to 4044 and there is another error: `Error running LR 7 Remote Debug: Unable to open debugger port (localhost:4044): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused"`

Answer (score 0):

Start you server with this argument 'jpda' to enable Java Platform Debugger Architecture on 8000 port.

If you use blade, start with this command:

```
blade server start -d
```